# How to reset Observable with a delay?

Tags: angular, rxjs

I'm trying to figure out how to "reset" a previous Observable that has a delay. My goal is such that when I click a button, it runs an action; at the end of that action, after waiting a defined amount of time, the action runs `finalize` to reset a value.

[Here is a Stackblitz of what I mean.](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-supd1g?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

If I click "Save new event", it will display a number. After 3 seconds, the number will disappear. The issue is if I click it once, it starts the delay--but then if I click it again after 1 second has passed, it will display the new number--but then 2 seconds later the number disappears since the first Observable sets `{saveSuccess: null}`.

Is there some RXJS magic that can accomplish what I want to do?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, there is indeed some *magic* that will cancel the previous delay on each new click (I think that's what you're after)

You need to use a `Subject` at the class level, and use `next` on the subject for each click. The `subject` should be set up in the `constructor` (or `ngOnInit`) as follows, with the `tap` operators inside the **pipe**

```
this.subject.pipe(
    switchMap(value => {
        return timer(1000).pipe(...)
    }),
    tap(...)
).subscribe()
```

The switchMap will cancel the previous timer on each subsequent click

Note: `timer` with an integer value works the same as a `delay`, but is itself an observable, rather than an operator

Comment: Returning timer does the trick like @Drenai suggested https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-jr65mg

Comment: just implemented this solution today .. what a coincidence :) . My requirement was to make a POST request after a certain time . I used timer and subscribed on that to make the post requests using mergeMap